# Kivy Text Input Widget: confused about 'bind' attribute

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I'm new to Kivy. I'm working on this code and I'm getting confused about what the bind function does.

Basically, the code below generates a text input and prints out the user's input.

```python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.username = TextInput(size = (300, 30), pos = (300, 30), multiline = False)
        # self.username.bind(on_text_validate = self.on_enter) ### first line
        self.username.bind(text= self.on_text)  ### second line
        self.add_widget(self.username)

    def on_enter(instance, value, secondvalue):
        print(secondvalue)

    def on_text(instance, value, secondvalue):
        print(secondvalue)


class ABCApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ABCApp().run()
```

Here's what I'm confused about. Why is it that only by printing out the `secondvalue` will I get the user's actual input? What is the `bind` function doing here? I looked at the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Also if I switch the commenting about such that the first line is commented out and the second line commented in, such that

```python
self.username.bind(on_text_validate = self.on_enter) ### first line
# self.username.bind(text= self.on_text)  ### second line
```

I am now referencing the function `on_enter` upon entering my text and pressing down the enter button. However, then I get the error message:

`TypeError: on_enter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'secondvalue'`

If I change the function `on_enter` to accept 2 arguments,

```
def on_enter(instance, secondvalue):
    print(secondvalue)
```

This now prints `<kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput object at 0x0000000003A432B8>`, but doesn't recover the text.

I'm confused about what Kivy is doing at their backend and I can't find any answers in their documentations. Why is it that `on_enter` accepts 2 arguments while `on_text` 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bind](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind) connects an event with a function.

In your case, the first event is the `on_text_validate` of the `TextInput` widget (the event that is emitted when you press Enter while on its text field), and the second is `text` (when the text of the field is changed).

These events trigger their dedicated functions using different arguments.
Both of them send as first argument the widget that produce them (the `TextInput` instance).
The `text` also sends the changed text.

To get the text of the `on_text_validate` event, you can get the `TextInput` `text` property like this:
`print(instance.text)`